# Debug grommet-cli sample-app in vscode

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, grommet

Loving [Grommet](http://grommet.io) and vscode.  Trying to get them to play together. I am able to get Express and vscode working as shown [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/runtimes/nodejs). I would like to get the [grommet-cli sample app](https://grommet.github.io/docs/get-started) to work similarly.  Express has one command to start: "npm start" where grommet-cli has two: "npm run dev-server" and "npm run dev" (not sure how to start them both in vscode. I think I may need [multi-session debugging](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14842#issuecomment-262730707)?). How do I setup launch.json to debug the sample app?  I'd like to be able to debug in IE/Edge. I've had some success in Chrome with the Debugger for Chrome extension.

Here is my current launch.json:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
    },
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "attach",
        "name": "Attach to Chrome",
        "port": 9222,
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/14842#issuecomment-262730707) appears to resolve the issue. Hopefully, it's been added to the latest version of VS.

```
"compounds": [
    {
        "name": "Node+Browser",
        "configurations": [ "Server", "Browser" ]
    }
],
"configurations" [
    {
        "name": "Browser",
        "type": "chrome",
        //...
    },
    {
        "name": "Server",
        "type": "node",
        //...
    }
]
```